# Why would Allah punish people he himself set seals on?

Tags: quran

in Baqarah 2:7, "Allah has set a seal upon their hearts and upon their hearing, and over their vision is a veil. And for them is a great punishment"

allah says he will punish the people he sets seals upon certain people's eyes hearts and ears. My question is, if god himself is the one who barred entry to someone from islam, then how is it justice for god to punish them for something he did? jazakallah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kind of patience Allah shows to us is unmatched. He gives sustenance to those who ask and those who don't. Those who recognize him and those who don't care about him. Those who do good in his name and those who just hate hearing the word of Allah/God.

If I come and steal from you, and then you forgive me, but then I steal again and you forgive me and then again and again and again. After 32 times you would finally give up. Would you believe him the 33rd time? possibly for your child you do it more, but then still after some point you just say, I have had enough and you just move on. Allah doesn't give up that easily,

- he send messengers
- he keeps forgiving us
- he delays his wrath
- he keeps showering us with his bounties
- he keeps giving us signs to have faith in him

### Prophet Noah preached for 900 years

If you ever read the gist of the story of Noah (PBUH), he preached his nation for 300 years but the nonbelievers beat him so bad, he was bleeding from his ears and passed out for 3 days, he asked God to send down his wrath, but the angels descended and said, Your lord is a merciful lord, go and guide them to the heavens again, another 300 years passed, and again Noah asked and again the Angels said your lord is a merciful lord, and this happened for a third time i.e. totally [900 years](https://quran.com/29/14) God didn't punish Noah's nation. Only after 900 years God said I shall punish this nation--when he showed enough patience and to prove that you are not of the believers even if time is given.

How merciful of a lord is our lord?!

The reason it's attributed to Allah is because our wisdom **is given**. It's not something we inherently own ourselves. The only thing we own as an attribute is **weakness**. He gave us wisdom. If we trash too much for too long then God is saying enough is enough. You don't want? Fine! I'll take it back. Hence it's attributed to him. But ultimately it's due to our own deeds. Think of it like the city taking away your driving credentials permanently, after you've ran over 10 people over the course of 30 years.

It's not exact science. But sometimes people like me disobey Allah. I repent immediately (or with some delay) or even if I don't, it's **not** [I forgot to mention 'not' in my comment below] like I take pride in doing what I did. Then there are others who openly disobey Allah left and right, take pride in doing it, enjoin others to follow, mock the religious, suppress the good, and restrict others from doing good (e.g. they force you to take off your hijab). They ignore every sign that Allah sends their way. For these people even if you give them 900 years they'll never return to Allah.

Comment: thank you for the answer, so to summarise, god sets seals on people  preventing them from repenting only if we disobey for long enough?

Comment: It's not exact science. But sometimes people like me disobey Allah. Then we go and repent (with some delay) or even if I don't, it's like I take pride in doing what I did. Then there are others who openly disobey Allah left and right and take pride in doing it, mock the religious, suppress the good, and restrict others from doing good e.g. they force you to take off your hijab. For these people even if you give them 900 years they'll never return to Allah.

Comment: i understand a little better now

Comment: Another anonymous downvote...

Comment: This does not answer the question.  If Allah chooses to put a seal on people's hearts, thus making them disbelievers, how is it righteous to punish them for this disbelief he created?

Comment: @inappropriateCode if you jump off a 100 story building and die, does gravity kill you or Allah? Gravity! Who created gravity? Allah! Did Allah kill you? If you can answer this tangent question I can then answer your question

Comment: @Honey Does the Quran say that Allah placed in people's hearts a desire to jump off buildings to their death?  Here it explicitly says that he sets a seal on their heart, in their ears, a veil upon their vision.  Your answer does not explain how this verse implies free will, if this is what you mean.

Comment: @inappropriateCode I can't continue the discussion if you don't want to reply to my comments.

Comment: @Honey This is not about what you or I think, this is about what the Quran explains.  If your answer is that the story of Noah explains the relationship between Allah as creator and human free will, this is not obvious.  The distinctions you make about "wisdom is given" and "our only attribute is weakness" are not cited explicitly, unless they are somewhere in the Noah story.  And anyway, none of this explains using scripture how 2:7 implies free will is possible outside of the choices of Allah.

Answer (score 1):

At first, those people had done this:

43. Have you seen him who **chose** his desire **as his god**? Would you be an agent for him?
44. Or do you assume that most of them hear or understand? They are just like cattle, but even more errant in **their way**.

Surah 25

--

And choosing implies an intentional action!